# How to implement refresh at the bottom of the list when user try to scroll down?

Tags: java, android, list, refresh, swiperefreshlayout

when I using SwipeRefreshLayout it will refresh when I try to scroll up at the top of the list. this time I want to apply the same thing but the trigger to refresh is when at the bottom of the list but still want to scroll down. Does anyone know how can I achieve that? really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance. however in java, please.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  code to res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id = "@+id/swipeRefresh"
   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
   android:layout_height = "match_parent"
   tools:context = ".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:gravity = "center"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
   <TextView
      android:id = "@+id/text"
      android:textSize = "30sp"
      android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
      android:text = "Hello World!"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

In the above code we have given swipeRefreshLayout as parent layout, when user swipe layout, it can refresh child view.

step3: code to src/MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.aji.myapplication;

import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;
   
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
      swipeRefresh = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
      swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
         @Override
         public void onRefresh() {
          //your stuff
            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

lets change hello wolrd to shafri

```
swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
   @Override
   public void onRefresh() {
      i++;
      textView.setText("shafri"+i);
      swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
   }
});
```

HappyCode!

Comment: hi. thank you for your answer. sorry, maybe I confuse with my own question haha. the code you show is when scroll down you can refresh right? but this time how can I refresh when the user tries to scroll down even at the end of the list?

Comment: I just did what you did. the normal swipe refresh. so this time I want inverted swipe refresh. emm you get what I mean?